# Packet drops after configuring Ethernet Bonding

Tags: ethernet

I am trying to configure Ethernet bonding for our servers . Both the Ethernet interface in my server are connected to two different network switches physically.

Looks like my Ethernet bonding configuring is OK , but I am seeing packet loss after configuring bonding . Sometimes the packet loss is around 90% .

My   /proc/net/bonding/bond0 looks like this

```
[root@ ~]# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 

Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.6.0 (September 26, 2009) 

Bonding Mode: adaptive load balancing 
Primary Slave: None 
Currently Active Slave: eth0 
MII Status: up 
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0 
Up Delay (ms): 0 
Down Delay (ms): 0 

Slave Interface: eth0 
MII Status: up 
Speed: 1000 Mbps 
Duplex: full 
Link Failure Count: 0 
Permanent HW addr: e4:e1:5b:d0:11:10 
Slave queue ID: 0 

Slave Interface: eth1 
MII Status: up 
Speed: 1000 Mbps 
Duplex: full 
Link Failure Count: 0 
Permanent HW addr: e4:e1:5b:d0:11:14 
Slave queue ID: 0 

[root@portaldb1 ~]# cat /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/mode 
balance-alb 6 

# cat /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/miimon 
0
```

OS I tried are RHEL 6.2 and CentOS 5.5 , seeing the packet drops in both OS

What I am missing in the configuration ? I tried connecting both the interface to the same switch , but still seeing the packets drops .  Any help/suggestions to resolve the issue will be hughly appreciated .

Comment: Are the drops mainly on the inactive interface of the bond?

Answer (score -1):

I have observed a similar situation on kernel 3.2.0

This recommendation helps:
http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg184521.html

Comment: Please give a summary, the link might break at any time.

Comment: patch for bond module (cut):
a/drivers/net/bonding/bond_main.c 
`
int bond_enslave(struct net_device *bond_dev, struct net_device *slave_dev)
...
-       if (!bond->params.fail_over_mac) {
+       if (!bond->params.fail_over_mac && !bond_is_lb(bond)) {
`

Comment: You should edit your answer rather than pasting unformatted code into a comment.